# Rest Services with jax b

Tags: java, rest

I have written this service in my rest app Rest Application:

```
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/companies")
public void removeCompany(Company company) throws AdminFacadeException {
AdminFacade facade = (AdminFacade)req.getSession(false).getAttribute("facade");
facade.removeCompany(company);
}
```

and this is where the error ocure in the dao layer:

```
@Override
public void removeCompany(Object obj, Company company) throws CompanyDBException {
Connection con = (Connection) obj;
String sql = "Delete from company where id=" + company.getCompanyId();
try {
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    int rowsChanged = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    if (rowsChanged == 0) {
        throw new CompanyDBException(
                "CompanyDAO: Failed to remove company. ID: " + company.getCompanyId() + " can not be found.");
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new CompanyDBException("CompanyDAO: Failed to remove company. ID: " + company.getCompanyId(), e);
}
}
```

When I created the company inside the service and set the id that  I got from the client there was no problem. However, now when  I changed the service to consume json, the eror(500)  occurred in the DB method in the line 
String sql=..........., it cant get the company.getCompanyId. more

String sql=...........,it cant get the company.getCompanyId.

I am giving some more information:  The company id is  automatically generated but  I cant see how it is change anything,  the company object getting transferred well, the id in my company bean is long, in the Company bean there is annotation @XmlRootElement.

Can someone explain what  am i missing

Comment: Just put a debugger and see what is going on..

Comment: Can you post the error message as well? Also it would be nice if you can post the company object. You should check if all necessary information are avaiable in the removeCompany method of your service and in the facade. You should also consider to use a PreparedStatement instead of an Statement in you DAO Layer.

Comment: the exception i get is null pointer exception in the line i mentioned before.

Comment: maybe because the id attribute is self generated the jax b when producing the object from the json leaves the id outside?

Comment: That means that you are getting the company object as Null. This could have two reasons either the object which is send to your service is empty or it get lost on the way to your DAO implementation. Could you please add the callstack of the removeCompany Method of your AdminFacade.

Comment: The Facade is getting Company, call DAO and send the same company all worked well thousands of times, also there is no connection to the self generated id because i changed the method to delete the company from the db with the company name also without success.